# Why OS is installed on C: drive by default?

Tags: windows

When I install an OS, particularly Windows on my machine, why does it's on C drive? And where is the name B:\ ?

I know A: is the floopy drive. I even know OS can be installed on any drive other than C:.

But what's makes it special about C:\ and not any other alphabet?